# Request filtering by verb and segments or url (IIS 7.5)

Tags: iis-7.5, request-filtering

How can I filter POST requests to the specified URL?

- `example.com/id123456789`

where the permanent part is `example.com/id`

- `example.com/id123456789/smth`

where the permanent part is `example.com/id.../smth`

Comment: What do you mean by *filter* here?  What do you want to happen when these URLs are requested?

Comment: IIS must return 404.xx error for POST-request.